# Parsing JSON in java: Malformed JSON: Unexpected 'C'

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

Good day,

I am parsing some JSON in java (a notification from a cisco CMX system). I've parsed a lot of JSON in my time but this one refuses to get parsed. I've tried several methods: a reader with lenient mode, plain gson, etc.

The JSON I parse is valid according to jsonlint, which leads me to believe it is a problem with the parser, or maybe some hidden characters that I am unable to sanitize out. This is the JSON I receive:

```
{
"startTime": "08:00",
"previousEndDate": null,
"startDate": "2016-02-17",
"title": "Visitors",
"executionTime": 29,
"value": {
    "primary": {
        "title": "TotalVisitors",
        "value": 16,
        "peakValue": 0,
        "breakdown": [{
            "title": "RepeatVisitors",
            "value": 11
        }, {
            "title": "NewVisitors",
            "value": 5
        }]
    },
    "average": {
        "title": "TotalVisitors",
        "value": 19,
        "peakValue": 0,
        "breakdown": [{
            "title": "RepeatVisitors",
            "value": 15
        }, {
            "title": "NewVisitors",
            "value": 4
        }]
    },
    "previousTimeRange": {
        "title": "TotalVisitors",
        "value": 23,
        "peakValue": 0,
        "breakdown": [{
            "title": "RepeatVisitors",
            "value": 19
        }, {
            "title": "NewVisitors",
            "value": 4
        }]
    }
},
"areas": [{
    "id": 20,
    "name": "CineCitta"
}],
"previousStartDate": "2016-02-16",
"endDate": null,
"endTime": "09:29"
}
```

It seems valid to me, and the object I try to parse it into has the correct fields.
I've tried filtering out \r \t \n \0 and some combinations between them.

The code I currently have in java is:

```
    String result = "{\"startTime\":\"08:00\",\"previousEndDate\":null,\"startDate\":\"2016-02-17\",\"title\":\"Visitors\",\"executionTime\":29,\"value\":{\"primary\":{\"title\":\"TotalVisitors\",\"value\":16,\"peakValue\":0,\"breakdown\":[{\"title\":\"RepeatVisitors\",\"value\":11},{\"title\":\"NewVisitors\",\"value\":5}]},\"average\":{\"title\":\"TotalVisitors\",\"value\":19,\"peakValue\":0,\"breakdown\":[{\"title\":\"RepeatVisitors\",\"value\":15},{\"title\":\"NewVisitors\",\"value\":4}]},\"previousTimeRange\":{\"title\":\"TotalVisitors\",\"value\":23,\"peakValue\":0,\"breakdown\":[{\"title\":\"RepeatVisitors\",\"value\":19},{\"title\":\"NewVisitors\",\"value\":4}]}},\"areas\":[{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"CineCitta\"}],\"previousStartDate\":\"2016-02-16\",\"endDate\":null,\"endTime\":\"09:29\"}";
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(result));
    reader.setLenient(true);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ClientInfo info = gson.fromJson(reader, ClientInfo.class);
```

The question is: Does anyone know how to debug a problem like this? are there sanitization techniques I can use? Other parsers?

EDIT: The code to clientinfo as requested (using project lombok, all fields are public):

```
@ToString
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class ClientInfo {
    String startTime;
    String previousEndDate;
    String startDate;
    String title;
    Integer executionTime;
    Value value;
    Area [] areas;
    String previousStartDate;
    String endDate;
    String endTime;
}

public class Value {
    public Visitors primary;
    public Visitors average;
    public Visitors previousTimeRange;
}

@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Area {
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Visitors {

    String title;
    Integer value;
    Integer peakValue;
    Record [] breakdown;
}
public class Record {
    public String title;
    public Integer value;
}
```

Thanks and good day

Comment: Please show the Code of the ClientInfo class

Comment: Other parsers: There's Moshi (by Square) - no idea if that will work better, though.

Comment: I added the code of clientinfo and the classes it references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a dumdum.

I assumed the parsing was what went wrong, but it was actually that my service was supposed to produce a JSON, where I did not return it as json, but the object itself resulting in a bad parsing.

Because I was so focused on the parsing I was doing I did not realize the error itself occurred on the implicit json parsing of the restful service.

That'll teach me not to test in a simple environment before moving my code to the a restful client.

Thanks and dumb greetings,

Dries

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = "{\"startTime\":\"08:00\",\"previousEndDate\":null,\"startDate\":\"2016-02-17\",\"title\":\"Visitors\",\"executionTime\":29,\"value\":{\"primary\":{\"title\":\"TotalVisitors\",\"value\":16,\"peakValue\":0,\"breakdown\":[{\"title\":\"RepeatVisitors\",\"value\":11},{\"title\":\"NewVisitors\",\"value\":5}]},\"average\":{\"title\":\"TotalVisitors\",\"value\":19,\"peakValue\":0,\"breakdown\":[{\"title\":\"RepeatVisitors\",\"value\":15},{\"title\":\"NewVisitors\",\"value\":4}]},\"previousTimeRange\":{\"title\":\"TotalVisitors\",\"value\":23,\"peakValue\":0,\"breakdown\":[{\"title\":\"RepeatVisitors\",\"value\":19},{\"title\":\"NewVisitors\",\"value\":4}]}},\"areas\":[{\"id\":20,\"name\":\"CineCitta\"}],\"previousStartDate\":\"2016-02-16\",\"endDate\":null,\"endTime\":\"09:29\"}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObj = parser.parse(result).getAsJsonObject();
ClientInfo info = gson.fromJson( jsonObj , ClientInfo.class);
```

You can give a try with above code.

Comment: The result is the same

Comment: @DriesDeRydt : Then you need to check `clientinfo` class code.